# Shorten url using bit.ly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, url, ios6

I have tried to Shorten urls using bit.ly. When i try to pass a static link it gives me a shorten url but when i try to pass a variable link it doesn't. 
here is my code....

```
Bitlyzer *bitlyzer = [[Bitlyzer alloc] initWithDelegate:self];

[bitlyzer shortURL:string];


[bitlyzer shortURL:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

When i pass this url it gives me a Shorten url but when i pass a variable string as shown above it doesn't give me shorten url.

Please give me your suggetions...

Comment: Please post the results of NSLog outputs of your variable urls before trying to shorten them. They're most probably not valid URLs.

Comment: @PatelManthan its happen when string url is not valid for NSURL and laos for bit.ly, so just remove this type of invalid format means remove space and then retain the string and then use it.. use my methods which are in answer.. and then try it.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time in our string some space is remain and so bitly not convert it and return null value so first remove the null or space from string and then try to convert it..

Add my these two methods in your `.m`  file and then use with your variable.. see the example also how to use it...

```
-(NSString*) trimString:(NSString *)theString {

     NSString *theStringTrimmed = [theString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
     return theStringTrimmed;
}

-(NSString *) removeNull:(NSString *) string {    

     NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"null"];
    //NSLog(@"in removeNull : %d  >>>> %@",range.length, string);
    if (range.length > 0 || string == nil) {
           string = @"";
    }
    string = [self trimString:string];
   return string;
}
```

And use this like bellow...

```
    string = [self removeNull:string];
    [string retain];

    Bitlyzer *bitlyzer = [[Bitlyzer alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [bitlyzer shortURL:string];
```